# Jest error with timers: environment has been torn down

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library, formik

I am trying to write a test using jest, Formik and react testing library, where the callback call I want to assert is triggered after a timeout.
I've been using jest and specifically fake timers for few years now, but this is the first time I see this weird error:

```
ReferenceError: You are trying to access a property or method of the Jest environment after it has been torn down.

      at runWithJestRealTimers (node_modules/@testing-library/dom/dist/helpers.js:46:8)
      at jestFakeTimersAreEnabled (node_modules/@testing-library/dom/dist/helpers.js:65:12)
      at node_modules/@testing-library/dom/dist/wait-for.js:45:71
      at waitFor (node_modules/@testing-library/dom/dist/wait-for.js:40:10) 
      at node_modules/@testing-library/dom/dist/wait-for.js:174:54
      at node_modules/@testing-library/react/dist/pure.js:57:22

 RUNS  src/components/FormUtils/SubmitOnEventRoot.test.tsx
C:\DEV\Abstract\telo-ui\node_modules\jest-runtime\build\index.js:1119       
      _getFakeTimers().useRealTimers();
                      ^

TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useRealTimers')
    at Object.useRealTimers (C:\DEV\Abstract\telo-ui\node_modules\jest-runtime\build\index.js:1119:23)
    at runWithJestRealTimers (C:\DEV\Abstract\telo-ui\node_modules\@testing-library\dom\dist\helpers.js:46:8)
    at jestFakeTimersAreEnabled (C:\DEV\Abstract\telo-ui\node_modules\@testing-library\dom\dist\helpers.js:65:12)
    at C:\DEV\Abstract\telo-ui\node_modules\@testing-library\dom\dist\wait-for.js:45:71
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at waitFor (C:\DEV\Abstract\telo-ui\node_modules\@testing-library\dom\dist\wait-for.js:40:10)
    at C:\DEV\Abstract\telo-ui\node_modules\@testing-library\dom\dist\wait-for.js:174:54
    at C:\DEV\Abstract\telo-ui\node_modules\@testing-library\react\dist\pure.js:57:22
    at batchedUpdates$1 (C:\DEV\Abstract\telo-ui\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js:21856:12)
    at act (C:\DEV\Abstract\telo-ui\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-test-utils.development.js:929:14)
```

Here is my test

```
beforeEach(() => {
    jest.useFakeTimers()
})

afterEach(() => {
    jest.runOnlyPendingTimers()
    jest.useRealTimers()
})

test('when deeply nested, then wraps deep children with a recursive approach', async () => {
    const handleSubmit = jest.fn()
    render(
        <AutoSubmitForm submitFn={handleSubmit} initValue={{ testFieldName: true }}> 
            <div>
                // the onChange will invoke Formik submit
                <Field component={Checkbox} submitOn="onChange" name="testFieldName" />
            </div>
        </AutoSubmitForm>,
    )
    const checkbox = getCheckBox()

    userEvent.click(checkbox)

    await waitFor(() => expect(checkbox).toBeChecked())
    // here comes the error
    jest.runAllTimers()
    await waitFor(() => expect(handleSubmit).toBeCalledTimes(1))
})
```

This is the component core part

```
const waitMs = async (ms?: number) => new Promise<void>((res) => { setTimeout(res, ms)})

[...]

await waitMs(100)
await onBeforeSubmit?.()
return formikSubmit()

[...]
```

My lib versions are:
"formik": "^2.2.9",
"@testing-library/react": "^11.2.6",
"react": "16.13.1"

Note that I created my app with CRA

EDIT 1

Here's the component code as requested. I just removed some non interesting clutter (e.g. ChildrenWrapper implementation that is out of this scope)

```
// from test file, where a simple test form is created
type FakeFormProps = {
    submitFn?: () => void
    initValue: { [key: string]: string | boolean }
    children: React.ReactNode
    onBeforeSubmit?: () => Promise<void>
}
const AutoSubmitForm = ({
    submitFn,
    initValue,
    children,
    onBeforeSubmit,
}: FakeFormProps) => {
    const handleOnSubmit = submitFn ?? jest.fn()
    return (
        <Formik onSubmit={handleOnSubmit} initialValues={initValue}>
            <Form>
                <SubmitOnEventRoot onBeforeSubmit={onBeforeSubmit}>
                    {children}
                </SubmitOnEventRoot>
            </Form>
        </Formik>
    )
}

// the actual component, called SubmitOnEventRoot
type SubmitOnEventRootProps = {
    children: React.ReactNode
    onBeforeSubmit?: () => Promise<void>
}

export const SubmitOnEventRoot = function SubmitOnEventRoot({
    children,
    onBeforeSubmit,
}: SubmitOnEventRootProps): JSX.Element {
    const { submitForm: formikSubmit } = useFormikContext()

    const handleSubmit = useCallback(async () => {
        await waitMs(100)
        await onBeforeSubmit?.()
        return formikSubmit()
    }, [formikSubmit, onBeforeSubmit])

    // just memoize ctx instance, so that it does not render pointlessly
    const ctx = useMemo(() => ({ submit: handleSubmit }), [handleSubmit])
    return (
        <SubmitOnEventContext.Provider value={ctx}>
            <ChildrenWrapper>{children}</ChildrenWrapper>
        </SubmitOnEventContext.Provider>
    )
}

const waitMs = async (ms?: number) =>
    new Promise<void>(res => {
        setTimeout(res, ms)
    })
```

Comment: You could try `jest.setTimeout(30000)` (30 seconds) which sets a timeout on the jest test itself. That way, if the test code isn't finished yet it won't be torn down until the jest timer runs out.

Comment: You should post more of the component code, in particular where and how the code you posted is used.

Comment: @possum I added the code you requested. Let me know if you need something else